# Replace column values (strings) in a dataframe based on partial overlap with a string vector

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(name = c("Donald Duck", "Daisy Duck", "Louie Duck", "Dewey D.", "Huey Duck"),
                 grade = c(44,39,17,78,43))
```

I also have a string vector with some values that are the same or similar as my df$name column.

```
stringvector <- c("Donald Duck", "Dewey Duck", "Daisy Duk")
```

I want to dplyr::filter df to contain only the rows that are in stringvector, like so:

```
df %>% dplyr::filter(name %in% stringvector)
```

But as you can see, the strings are not in all cases identical, so this does not work.

What is an elegant way to check if part of the string (for example, only 'Dewey') is identical in both df and stringvector, and then to filter df to contain only rows that have some overlap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)

df |> filter(word(name) %in% word(stringvector))
```

Output:

```
         name grade
1 Donald Duck    44
2  Daisy Duck    39
3    Dewey D.    78
```

[`word()`](https://stringr.tidyverse.org/reference/word.html) by default, gets the first word in a string, so `word(name) %in% word(stringvector)` checks if the first word of name is in the first words of the strings in stringvector.

The problem with doing a more comprehensive overlap check (check if *any* word in name is in any string in stringvector) is the 'Duck' in 'Louie Duck' would match the 'Duck' in 'Donald Duck'.

Comment: Nice, thanks. I get you remark on the problem if you would want to do it based on any word in the string. Actually, my example here is not very accurate. Is there also a way to do this that does not only rely on the first word in a string, if there are no overlaps like 'duck'? Maybe I should adapt my example.

Comment: @Lieke it depends what you're looking for- see the last part of my answer!

Comment: if you match anything, then you'll get false matches, because of the Louie Duck problem. One way around this would be to create a vector of all of the words in stringvector, remove the ones you don't want, and then match on that with all words in the name column

Comment: I found a solution for my problem by throwing word() in lapply: l <- lapply(stringvector, FUN = function(x) word(x, start = 1:3)) %>% unlist() and then df %>% filter(df$name %in% l)

Comment: @Lieke post it as an answer so I can upvote you! :-)

Answer (score 1):

As an addition to Mark's answer, in case you don't want to rely only on the first word (so not this particular case because of the 'Louie Duck' problem), you can do as follows:

```
l <- lapply(stringvector, FUN = function(x) word(x, start = 1:3)) %>% unlist()
df %>% filter(df$name %in% l)
```